# query multiple values in function and return inside 1 variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

I would like to write a function which query's the database for:

```
SELECT m.title, m.firstname, m.surname 
FROM contact c
LEFT JOIN membership m
ON c.contactID=m.contactID
```

You see i could have many contacts returned from the above query. I would like to return the results into a variable in the function so that I may use globally.

I want the results of the function to show up like this:

```
Mr John Test
Mrs Jane Smith
```

I want to write a function which returns @MemberNames like the example with John and Jane...

This is what i have attempted so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnGetMemberNames 
    (   
    @membershipID int,    
    )
RETURNS int
AS

BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @MemberNames varchar(300)

SELECT m.title, m.firstname, m.surname 
FROM contact c
LEFT JOIN membership m
ON c.contactID=m.contactID
WHERE membershipID=@membershipID

RETURN @MemberNames

END
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for with your question. Could you elaborate a little on what the rows in the database look like and what exactly you want the output to be? Thanks!

Comment: I want to write a function which returns @MemberNames like the example with John and Jane...

Comment: Ahh, well it seems as though @Azzi has the right idea with his answer. You can concat the select items into one full name

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your select statement as follows and then create a function that returns this value:

```
SELECT (m.title + ' ' + m.firstname + ' ' + m.surname) 
FROM contact c
LEFT JOIN membership m
ON c.contactID=m.contactID
```

The example above uses string concatenation and creates a single column under the column heading Name from multiple columns, with the title of the person followed by a space, then the first name of the person followed by a space, then last name.

Your function will look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION your_function (@ID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @name_to_return AS VARCHAR(50);
  SELECT  @name_to_return =
             (m.title + ' ' + m.firstname + ' ' + m.surname) 
  FROM contact c
  LEFT JOIN membership m
    ON c.contactID=@ID;
  RETURN @name_to_return ;
END;
```

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Didn't see your edit until I gave my answer.  You are missing several ';' and your return type is not correct. Check the template I gave you.

Comment: Thanks but how do i call this function or use it in a query window?

Comment: @PriceCheaperton SELECT function(args...) AS result

Answer (score 2):

Making this an answer because the @ variable was being interpreted as a @user directive...

@PriceCheaperton -- See what Azzi wrote:
You need to set your return variable equal to a value.  Right now you're just declaring it as an empty varchar.

```
SELECT @MemberNames = (m.title + ' ' + m.firstname + ' ' + m.surname) FROM 
// the rest of your query here
```

...like Azzi said.